# Add GameObject on position of a mesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using an FBX 3d model with about 100 meshes. I want to select one of this meshes and place a GameObject (cube) on the same position to use it later in the code to focus the camera on it. The cube has been added but is not on the right position - it's out off the viewport instead of. Don't know how to determine the correct coordinates of the meshes in Unity.

```
Object prefab = Resources.Load("my_prefab"); // Assets/Resources/Prefabs/prefab1.FBX
var obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(370, 105, 100), Quaternion.identity);
obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(150, 150, 150);

GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.name = "my_cube";
cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
cube.transform.parent = obj.transform;

var meshFilter = FindMesh(obj.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>(), "head");

List<Vector3> vector3List = new List<Vector3>();

for (int i = 0; i < meshFilter.mesh.vertices.Length; ++i)
{
    vector3List.Add(obj.transform.TransformPoint(meshFilter.mesh.vertices[i]));
}

cube.transform.localPosition = vector3List[0];
Camera.main.transform.LookAt(obj.transform);

public MeshFilter FindMesh(MeshFilter[] mesh, string name)
{
    foreach (MeshFilter meshFilter in mesh)
    {
        if (meshFilter.name == name)
        {
            return meshFilter;
        }
    }
        return null;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code? I think it has something to do with the scaling of the prefab.
THX for your help!!

**Edit:**

Updated code and implemented changes suggested by Anis Brachemi but it's still not working. The cube is now child of the head component but when the camera looks at the cube the head isn't visible in the viewport.

```
Object prefab = Resources.Load("ironman"); // Assets/Resources/Prefabs/prefab1.FBX
var obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(370, 105, 100), Quaternion.identity);
obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(150, 150, 150);

GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
cube.name = "my_cube";
cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);

var components = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>();
foreach (Component c in components)
{
    if (c.name == "head")
    {
        cube.transform.parent = c.transform;
        break;
    }
}

cube.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
Camera.main.transform.LookAt(cube.transform);
```

this is the fbx I'm using: https://free3d.com/de/3d-model/iron-man-2-11174.html

I'm new in Unity. So I don't know the best way to focus the camera to child compontents of a gameobject. Maybe  there is better way to do it...

Comment: Why do you have one FBX with 100 separate meshes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the GameObject I've added was wrong. I changed the localPosition of the cube to the vector of the head and it works

```
        var head = GameObject.Find("head");
        var vertex = head.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices[0];

        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
        cube.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("my_parent").transform;
        cube.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
        cube.transform.localPosition = vertex;

        Camera.main.transform.LookAt(cube.transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

Off-question comment, this code

```
List<Vector3> vector3List = new List<Vector3>();

for (int i = 0; i < meshFilter.mesh.vertices.Length; ++i)
{
    vector3List.Add(obj.transform.TransformPoint(meshFilter.mesh.vertices[i]));
}

cube.transform.localPosition = vector3List[0];
```

Can be simplified to

```
cube.transform.localPosition = obj.transform.TransformPoint(meshFilter.mesh.vertices[0]);
```

So to answer your question, I don't get why you are using Vertices instead of just putting the cube in the head object but anyways if it is necessary for your case then, I suggest you try lowering your cube size by a LOT, adding a line `cube.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;` to prevent the cube from reacting to collisions and finally change `localPosition` to `position`

**EDIT**

If I may add, if you just want the camera to follow the head, it would be simpler if you did not create cube at all, just make the camera look at the Head object. Outside of your code, declare a variable `Transform head;`

```
if(head == null)
    var components = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Component>();
    foreach (Component c in components)
    {
        if (c.name == "head")
        {
            head = c.transform;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Camera.main.transform.LookAt(head);
```

And remove all the unnecessary code of the cube creation.

Comment: Thx for your help! I used vertices because I'm a Unity newbie. So I've implemented your suggestion to just put the cube in the head object (see my edit note in my posting). Unfortunately it's not working as expected